# Alternative for Either pattern matching

Tags: scala

Is there any for the following kind of pattern matching of Either? Something like map on both Right and Left to return an Either of different type. I don't want to specify Left and Right everywhere.

```
val v:Either[Throwable, String] = Right("Hello")
val result: Either[Int, String] = v match {
  case Left(ex) => Left(ex.getMessage.size)
  case Right(m) => Right(m)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the following, you don't have to use pattern matching

```
v.left.map(_.getMessage).right.map(_)
```

Comment: i guess v.left.map(_.getMessage.size) is enough